# Which version of gradle version I need to download for android studio 4.0.1

Tags: java, android, gradle

Recently i have installed android **`studio 4.0.1`** but it shows the gradle is corrupt and android studio is showing **`"gradle project sync failed"`**.

So i am not sure that which version of **`gradle`** i need to download and from where.

Other than this do I need to download any java files for android studio or is it downloaded during the installation of android studio

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio 4.0.x you need at least Gradle 6.1.1

[Source](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#4-0-0)